# Highcharts: initialize Highcharts before showing new charts on an Ajax-driven page

Tags: highcharts

I have a page which has a few links. Clicking on a link generates a list of different charts in the bottom of the page without page reload. Put it another way, each link clears previous charts, gets new data from the server, invokes Highcharts to draw new charts. No page reload.

Here comes the issue.

I am using the following Javascript to collect the charts on the page and send the data to the server.

```
var svgArray=[];
$(Highcharts.charts).each(function(i, chart){    
    if (chart) {
        svgArray.push(chart.getSVG());
    }
});
```

I notice that Highcharts.charts array grows by **ADDING** new charts to its end of when a link is clicked. I dont need old charts. I just want to collect new charts.

How can I initialize Highcharts or Highcharts.charts when a link is clicked.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: I said you that before.. that's how it works. You shouldn't clear that array, its for read options only. Why can't you simply create your own array with existing charts and use that array..?

Comment: Pawel, thanks for your input! "create your own array with existing charts and use that array". I have no idea how it can be done. You mean when I use "var mychart =container.chart(options)" and push mychart into an array I create? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. With one exception: not `var mychart =container.chart(options)` but `var mychart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);` or `var mychart = $("#container").highcharts(options).highcharts();`

Comment: Pawel, thanks for your confirmation. Did you see any problem with the answer/solution I provided earlier? I found it works well in my situation. Cheers.

Comment: No, it's fine. Since it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did and it appears to get rid of charts created earlier. When a link is clicked and before the new charts get drawn, I try to destroy all charts the following way:

```
    $(Highcharts.charts).each(function(i, chart){    
        if (chart) {
            chart.destroy();
        }
    });
```

It seems working, but I am not sure if this is the right or best way or it can help others. I love to hear the input from experts.

Thanks!